# Visual Studio XAML editor: when cutting and pasting a chunk of code, how do I keep it collapsed?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, editor

When designing a WPF application in Visual Studio, I often need to move big chunks of code, for example, to change the order of big, nested controls. Before doing it, I often collapse everything with CTRL+M to make this operation easier. I select the collapsed code chunk that I want to move, and press CTRL+C.

However, as soon as I press CTRL+V to paste the code in the clipboard, the editor automatically expands it with all it's nested controls. Then I have to scroll miles up the editor to get back to the "-" sign in order to collapse that section again.

It is very annoying. How can I disable this behavior, so that the pasted code remains collapsed?

Comment: I don't think you can. Two work rounds i can think of. First is code/xaml regions. You could add one and paste within it. Or. Macros. You can probably use automation to insert a region or something, insert your clipboard, select the region, collapse it and remove the region. Or just some combination of activedocument navigate and select then collapse.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Andy, but that would be an awfully complicated solution for such a simple thing... I mean, what I'm asking is like one of the most basic functionalities that any respectable IDE should have to begin with. Surely there must be an easier way?

Comment: Why would there be?  I've never felt the need for collapsed pasting of xaml myself.

Comment: @Andy, well, I am not sure how you handle it, but if I need to paste a 200 line section of code, and it suddenly unfold itself, the time spent having to collapse it manually every time really adds up.